# Handling effects on the shell environment with the shake build system

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I am running bash on windows (not the fancy new thing on windows 10, mingw bash) and from there `shake`. From what I understand it is possible for a command on windows to edit the environment of `cmd`. In my usecase I don't want to make assumptions on how the environment will be changed, I just want the next command to run in that changed environment. Is that possible?

The ideal scenario would be something like

```
(Environment env, Stdout out) <- cmd Shell (Cwd dir) "path/to/script.cmd" [arg1] [arg2]
-- Do stuff with out
cmd Shell (Cwd dir) (Env env) "env/dependent/command.cmd"
```

I would also be happy with running both commands in the same shell even if it means that I can't `Do stuff with out` but I couldn't figure out how to do that either

I guess in makefile terms what I want is similar to `.ONESHELL:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `cmd` invocation in Shake is separate, so any environment variables don't persist. Assuming you want to treat `script.cmd` as a black box, there are two options:

1. Run both commands in a single step. Something like: `Stdout out <- cmd Shell (Cwd dir) "path/to/script.cmd" arg1 arg2 "&& env/dependent/command.cmd"`.
2. Capture the environment from the first command and pass it into the second. You can capture the environment by running `path/to/script.cmd .... && set`, capturing that with `Stdout`, parsing it, and then supplying it with `Env`.

If you want to reuse the `Env` more than once then the second is probably faster, but both should work.

A worked implementation of the second approach, including `set` output parser, is available [here (by @fakedrake)](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/447#issuecomment-217168924).